# How to reduce code complexity in Climbing the Leaderboard?

Tags: kotlin

I have an following issue: I'm trying to complete one of hackerrank exercises. Climbing the Leaderboard. There is excersise description from hackerrank:

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the
> leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses Dense
> Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the
> leaderboard.
>
> Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the
> next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
>
> For example, the four players on the leaderboard have high scores of
> 100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3,
> respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105, her rankings after
> each game are 4, 3 and 1.

I tried to do as simplest solution, as possible:

```
import java.io.*
import java.math.*
import java.security.*
import java.text.*
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.*
import java.util.function.*
import java.util.regex.*
import java.util.stream.*
import kotlin.collections.*
import kotlin.comparisons.*
import kotlin.io.*
import kotlin.jvm.*
import kotlin.jvm.functions.*
import kotlin.jvm.internal.*
import kotlin.ranges.*
import kotlin.sequences.*
import kotlin.text.*

// Complete the climbingLeaderboard function below.
fun climbingLeaderboard(scores: Array<Int>, alice: Array<Int>): Array<Int>{
    var scoresList = scores.distinct().toMutableList()
    var finalArray = IntArray(alice.size)
    for(i in alice.indices) {
        scoresList.add(alice[i])
        scoresList.sortDescending()
        finalArray[i] = scoresList.indexOf(alice[i]) + 1
        scoresList.remove(alice[i])
    }
    return finalArray.toTypedArray()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val scoresCount = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()

    val scores = scan.nextLine().split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()

    val aliceCount = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()

    val alice = scan.nextLine().split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()

    val result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)

    println(result.joinToString("\n"))
}
```

But I am still getting time out from hackerrank. So I want to ask, if somebody has any idea of how to reduce cyclomatic complexity.
Thank you for your help!
Sorry for my bad english... hope you all understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointers approach here:

1. Sort both arrays in descending order
2. Loop for each score of Alice, initialize second pointer to the beginning of leaderboard. Store current rank - `currentRank`, initialize with 1.
3. At the beginning of iteration uphold such invariant: current leaderboard score is first one less than Alice's score. If after doing this you moved the second pointer, increment current rank. If the second pointer is past the size of leaderboard, do nothing.
4. Set Alice's rank for score on this iteration to `currentRank`

As you see, you don't need to remove repeating scores in the leaderboard, since the procedure of upholding aformentioned invariant will skip repeating scores, and `currentRank` will be updated only in the case the pointer was moved.

Overall complexity of this solution is `O(NlogN + MlogM)`, where `N` and `M` are the sizes of leaderboard and Alice's scores list.

In Java it would be like:

```
// assume alice and scores are sorted in descending order

var currentRank = 1, currentPos = 0
for (var i = 0; i < alice.size; i++) {
    var update = false
    while (currentPos < scores.size && scores[currentPos] > alice[i]) {
        ++currentPos
        update = true
    }

    if (update)
        ++currentRank

    finalArray[i] = currentRank
}
```

Comment: Thank you for idea. Could you please send me your code for this solution (no matter which language) so I can be sure I fully understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.util.Scanner` is quite slow for I/O firstly you can decrease time as mentioned in [Notes on using Kotlin for Competitive Programming](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71089), you can use a `BufferedReader` on the `System.in` for the fastest reading of large datasets:

```kotlin
val reader = System.`in`.bufferedReader()
fun readLn() = reader.readLine()!!
fun readInt() = readLn().toInt()
fun readInts() = readLn().split(" ").map { it.toInt() }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scoresCount = readInt()
    val scores = readInts()
    val aliceCount = readInt()
    val alice = readInts()

    val result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
    println(result.joinToString("\n"))
}
```

Then for reducing the complexicity:

```kotlin
// let n element in scores and m in alice
fun climbingLeaderboard(scores: List<Int>, alice: List<Int>): List<Int> {
    // O(n)
    val sortedList = scores.asSequence().distinct().sortedDescending().toList()

    // O(m)
    return alice.map { aliceScore ->
        // Minimum steps to find first index smaller than aliceScore, upto max of O(n)
        val v = sortedList.indexOfFirst { it <= aliceScore }
        (if (v == -1) sortedList.size else v)+1
    }
}
```

Maximum complexity via above approach will be `O(n+n*m)`

Answer (score 0):

From constraints of the problem:

> The existing leaderboard is in descending order.

> Alice's scores are in ascending order.

You don't need to change the leaderboard, because Alice's scores are always in ascending order. But `indexOf` is too slow (`O(N)`). Since the leaderboard is in descending order you can use `binarySearch` (`O(logN)`) with ReverseOrder comparator

`O(N logN)` solution

```
fun climbingLeaderboard(scores: List<Int>, alice: List<Int>): List<Int> {
    val scoresList = scores.distinct()
    return alice.map {
        val searchResult = scoresList.binarySearch(it, reverseOrder())
        if (searchResult < 0) -searchResult else searchResult + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `distinct()` O(n^2)?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `Iterable.distinct` uses `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: Ah, OK. I never realized `HashSet.add` was only *O(1)*. I guess because checking for hash collisions is way faster than exhaustively searching. So `distinct()` is *O(n)*, right?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, O(n) on average

Answer (score 0):

Since Alice's scores are also sorted, you don't have to repeatedly check indices or search for values. You can iterate one time and count as you go.

I think this is *O(n)*:

```
fun climbingLeaderboard(scores: Array<Int>, alice: Array<Int>): Array<Int>{
    val highScores = scores.distinct()
    var checkedIndex = highScores.size - 1
    var lastCheckedScore = highScores.last()
    val topScore = highScores.first()
    return alice.map { aliceScore ->
        while (aliceScore >= lastCheckedScore && checkedIndex > 0) {
            lastCheckedScore = highScores[--checkedIndex]
        }
        if (aliceScore >= topScore) 1 else checkedIndex + 2
    }.toTypedArray()
}
```